# Exclude <script></script> tags and everything that is in between them JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a chrome extension that changes color of letters on a webpage for a school project. I made it so it changes color but the problem I'm facing is that it "corupts" everything that is in between

```
 <script></script>
```

tags so when a page wants to load a script it cant because there is an HTML code in it.

Here is the JavaScript code i have so far:

```js
window.onload = function(){

var letters = ["b", "d", "a", "o"];
var results;
var resultb;
var colors = ["#b32400", "#006622", "#cc0099", "#0000ff"];
var re;
  
for (x = 0; x < letters.length; x++) {
  results = letters[x].fontcolor(colors[x]);
  resultb = letters[x].toUpperCase().fontcolor(colors[x]);

  res = new RegExp("(" + letters[x] + ")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "g");
  reb = new RegExp("(" + letters[x].toUpperCase() + ")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "g");

  $("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(res, results));
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(reb, resultb));
  });
}
}
```

Comment: using regexp on HTML will summon [Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)!!

Comment: [Liquid pain!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/238884)

Comment: @JaromandaX so how to do it then? XML parser?

Comment: Yes, the recommended way to parse XML is an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

File called scriptinject:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json with your code above.

In manifest:

```
    "content_scripts": {
    "matches": ["http://*"],
    "js": ["scriptinject.js"]
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
```

script.js contains your code

Comment: So if I understand this properly this injects the script itself into the webpage?

Comment: Yes, it creates a <script></script> with the code from script.js in it inside the <head></head>

Comment: So do I have to write this code into the background.js file?

Comment: No, in contentscripts you do this: